# Change and Save Application-scope Settings for next application session In WPF

Tags: wpf, settings

I'm using both user-scope and application-scope Settings in WPF.

My application usually connects to DB in localhost for developing, but occasionally I need to connect to remote DB server which final application should connect to.

DB Address settings are stored in application-scope Settings.

Application-level Settings cannot be changed during runtime, so I have to open and edit my .config files with Notepad every time whenever I need to before I start the application.

I want to update application-scope Settings in My application at runtime. But need not be applied for the current session, It is okay for the next(and after) application session.

Is there any easy solution to this? If not exist, is it ok to parse and write the .config file directly in my application?

Comment: Yes, it is ok to parse the .config file and update it from your application.

Comment: @ShivaniKatukota Thanks... walk through another routine...

Answer (score -1):

You can have XML or JSON file as settings. Try to read the settings and display it in a window and save the contents again in JSON/XML files.

By the way you can achieve the Application settings read and edit during run time.

Comment: I made Textbox bound to one of application-level setting(TwoWay mode) in my application, but It is not working because it is a read-only setting.

Comment: Yes it won't work..you are right application settings are read-only.

Comment: Since your are using WPF application changing the Application settings is possible to reflect dynamically. We have achieved it.

Comment: @ArunAradhya How can you achieve that? I did some reflections, It seems work, success to change the value of Settings instance. But Settings.Default.Save() doesn't save the changes into .config file.

Comment: Consider using registry or some XML files other than the.config files.